# How to get data from an array if the array located in object using the map method?

Tags: javascript

there is Api - an array:

```
[
{"id":1,"firstName":"Alex","lastName":"Creel","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":2,"firstName":"Todd","lastName":"Drek","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":3,"firstName":"Jim","lastName":"Sparou","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":4,"firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Limls","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":5,"firstName":"Jack","lastName":"Retnd","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"}
]
```

using fetch, I get Api - an array that becomes a data object (I don’t write App.js code so that the question is not too long)
and using the map method, in the form of a table, I display the data I need on the page:

```
export default props => (
  <table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {props.data.map(item => (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{item.id}</td>
        <td>{item.firstName}</td>
        <td>{item.lastName}</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
  </tbody>
  </table>
)
```

there will be such a table on the screen:

[image]

But I have this second strange Api:

```
{"group":{"first":[
{"id":1,"firstName":"Alex","lastName":"Creel","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":2,"firstName":"Todd","lastName":"Drek","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":3,"firstName":"Jim","lastName":"Sparou","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":4,"firstName":"Tom","lastName":"Limls","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"},
{"id":5,"firstName":"Jack","lastName":"Retnd","email":"BGibson@placerat.ly","phone":"(898)979-8452"}
]}}
```

and I have a question how can I change this part of the code:

```
{props.data.map(item => (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{item.id}</td>
        <td>{item.firstName}</td>
        <td>{item.lastName}</td>
      </tr>
```

how to make the map method work with my second api on the screen and get exactly the same list of names as with the first api?
I tried like this:

```
{props.data.group.first.map(item =>
```

But then the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to accommodate both cases, perhaps you can just do a quick check before you map over the items to see which case you're currently using. For example:

```
const arr = props.data.group && props.data.group.first ? 
  props.data.group.first : props.data;

arr.map(item => { ... });
```

Comment: error:
./src/Table/Table.js
  Line 16:16:  'item' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 17:14:  'item' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 18:14:  'item' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 19:14:  'item' is not defined  no-undef

all code in codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-poincare-w47th

Comment: I just took a peek... looks like you mean `props.item` ?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add a component of the app,js file in the sandbox, please look again, maybe you will better understand my task and why i have a error.
My error after I add your code to project(screenshot):
http://i.piccy.info/i9/c9bf853fbdc10013447813bc4c057c8f/1572207754/18059/1334636/Screenshot_6.jpg

Comment: I see, you appear to be trying to do some things in the JSX itself rather than outside. Please see this fixed version: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-pine-8hptz

Comment: And, I still wanted to ask you. why do we need this check?

const arr = props.data.group && props.data.group.first ? 
props.data.group.first : props.data;

Comment: so `props.data.group && props.data.group.first` will make sure `group` and `first` exist before assuming we should use that logic. If they don't exist, then we just use `props.data`

Comment: I just don't understand why we check for ```props.data.group && props.data.group.first```? why the map method does not want to iterate my array that is situated in object when when I write this way:
```{props.data.group.first.map(item =>```
without check that you offered?
I just want to understand how it works

Comment: My assumption was you wanted to account for both situations (where props.data is the array or where props.data.group.first is the array). If it can actually only be the second case, then your way would work fine!